# How to get direction of rotation from linear velocity of pendulum?

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, physics

I have a class called `Pendulum` which has getters and setters allowing it to calculate its angle of rotation if given some inputs like: initial angle, current time (which is used to calculate dt), etc.

I am using THREE.js

One of these getter methods is called `get angularVelocity()` and this one has a logic error. I can't figure out what this error is so I can fix it.

The getter is defined:

```js
get angularVelocity() {
    // we have v and radius => w = v/r
    // positive w means cw, negative means acw rotation
    const linearSpeed = linearVelocity.length();
    const wMagnitude = linearSpeed / pendulumLength;

    const axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    const w = new THREE.Vector3();
    w.crossVectors(axis, v);
    w.setLength(wMagnitude);

    const dotProduct = w.dot(axis);
    const isClockwise = dotProduct < 0;
    return isClockwise ? wMagnitude : -wMagnitude;
}
```

The problem is that the pendulum rotates clockwise no matter the direction of the linear velocity. Why is this and how can I fix my logic so that the pendulum rotates in a direction as if a force is applied to the end of the pendulum along the velocity vector?

Ie the direction of rotation calculated here does not follow the direction of linear velocity.

I have added my full code below in case the error is actually elsewhere:

```js
class PendulumScene {
    #scene;
    #camera;
    #renderer;
    #pendulum;
    #pendulumData;
    #parent;
    #g;
    #clock;
    constructor(pendulumLengths, startingAngles) {
        this.#scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.#camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        this.#camera.position.z = 2;
        this.#camera.lookAt(0,0,0);

        this.#renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this.#renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild(this.#renderer.domElement);

        this.#g = new THREE.Vector3(0,-1,0); // acceleration due to gravity
        this.#clock = new THREE.Clock();

        this.populateScene(pendulumLengths, startingAngles);
        this.animate();
    }

    populateScene(pendulumLengths, startingAngles) {
        const len = pendulumLengths[0]; // todo - make it loop thru all lengths to make it a double/tripple etc pendulum
        const angle = startingAngles[0];

        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x33bb33});
        this.#pendulum = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.BoxGeometry(.25, len, .25),
            material
        );

        this.#parent = new THREE.Object3D();
        this.#parent.add(this.#pendulum);
        this.#parent.position.set(0, len, 0);
        this.#pendulum.position.set(0, -len/2, 0);
        this.#parent.rotation.z = angle;

        this.#scene.add(this.#parent);

        const pendulumVelocity = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
        this.#pendulumData = new Pendulum(len, angle, this.#g, this.#clock);
    }


    animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.animate();
        });
        this.#renderer.render(this.#scene, this.#camera);


        const rotation = this.calcPendulumRotation();
        // todo - this.#parent.rotation.set(...rotation);
    }


    calcPendulumRotation() {
        const newTheta = this.#pendulumData.theta;
        this.#parent.rotation.z = newTheta;

        if(this.velocityArrow) {
            this.#scene.remove(this.velocityArrow);
            this.#scene.remove(this.accelerationArrow);
        }

        const v = this.#pendulumData.getVelocityArrow();
        const a = this.#pendulumData.getAccelerationArrow();

        const origin = new THREE.Vector3(0,-1,1);
        const length = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
        origin.add(length);

        const vLen = v.clone().length();
        v.normalize();
        this.velocityArrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(v, origin, vLen, 0xff0000);

        const aLen = a.clone().length();
        a.normalize();
        this.accelerationArrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(a, origin, aLen, 0x008800);

        this.#scene.add(this.velocityArrow, this.accelerationArrow);
    }
}


class Pendulum {
    #oldVelocity; // the velocity at a very small time, dt, earlier

    #oldAngularVelocity;

    #oldAcceleration;

    #radiusVector;
    #length;

    #g;
    #gSize;
    
    #clock;
    #currentDt;
    
    #oldTheta;

    #dampingFactor;
    #axis;

    constructor(length, initialTheta, g, clock) {
        this.#radiusVector = new THREE.Vector3(length,0,0);
        this.#length = length;

        this.#g = g;
        this.#gSize = Math.abs(g.y);
        
        this.#clock = clock;
        this.#currentDt = undefined;        

        this.#oldVelocity = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
        this.#oldAcceleration = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);

        this.#oldAngularVelocity = 0;

        this.#oldTheta = initialTheta;
        /*if(this.#initialTheta > Math.PI) {
            console.log(this.#initialTheta*(360/2));
            this.#initialTheta = -2*Math.PI + this.#initialTheta;
            console.log(this.#initialTheta*(360/2));
        }*/
        this.#dampingFactor = 1;
        this.#axis = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
    }

    get deltaTime() {
        return this.#clock.getDelta(); // always around ~0.002: this.#clock.getDelta();
    }
    get t() {
        return this.#clock.getElapsedTime();
    }

    get acceleration() {
        /*let dir = -1;
        if(this.#oldTheta < 0) {
            dir = 1;
        }*/
        const mag = this.#gSize * Math.sin(this.#oldTheta);
        const direcAngle = this.#oldTheta + /*dir**/Math.PI/2;
        const a = new THREE.Vector3(0, mag, 0).applyAxisAngle(this.#axis, direcAngle);
        a.multiplyScalar(this.#dampingFactor);
        this.#oldAcceleration = a;
        return a;
    }

    get velocity() { // linear velocity
        this.#currentDt = this.deltaTime;

        const averageAcceleration = this.#oldAcceleration.clone().add(this.acceleration.clone());
        averageAcceleration.divideScalar(2);

        const dv = averageAcceleration.multiplyScalar(this.#currentDt);
        
        const v = this.#oldVelocity.clone().add(dv);
        this.#oldVelocity = v;

        return v;
    }

    get angularVelocity() {
        // we have v and radius => w = v/r
        // positive w means anticlockwise, negative means clockwise
        
        /*
        let dir = 1;
        if(velocity.y < 0) { // todo problem here - decide which way w is
            dir = -1;
        }
        const w = dir*velocity.length() / this.#length;
        // this.#oldAngularVelocity = w;
        return w;*/

        const v = this.velocity.clone();
        const wMagnitude = v.length() / this.#length;
        const axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

        const w = new THREE.Vector3();
        w.crossVectors(axis, v);
        w.setLength(wMagnitude);

        const dotProduct = w.dot(axis);
        const isClockwise = dotProduct < 0;
        return isClockwise ? wMagnitude : -wMagnitude;
    }

    get integratedAngularVelocity() {
        // integrated angular velocity means the change in theta over dt
        // where dt is stored in this.#currentDt
        /*const oldAngularVelocity = this.#oldAngularVelocity; // at time 0
        const newAngularVelocity = this.angularVelocity; // at time dt
        // integrate approximately (trapezium rule, since dt doesnt tend to 0 especially on slow computers)
        const averageAngularVelocity = (oldAngularVelocity+newAngularVelocity)/2;
        const deltaTheta = averageAngularVelocity * this.#currentDt;
        return deltaTheta;*/

        // calcualte area of thin slice of w over t graph, call it dTheta
        const dTheta = this.angularVelocity * this.#currentDt;
        return dTheta;
    }

    get theta() {
        // we have theta0 and w 
        // => integrate w and add on to theta0 to get new theta
        // because the integration getter returns the area of a small slice of the graph of w over t, not the entire area 
        const newTheta = this.integratedAngularVelocity + this.#oldTheta;
        this.#oldTheta = newTheta;
        return newTheta;
    }

    getVelocityArrow() {
        return this.#oldVelocity;
    }
    getAccelerationArrow() {
        return this.#oldAcceleration;
    }
}


const pendulumScene = new PendulumScene(
        [1], // pendulum lengths
        [Math.PI/4], // starting angles
    );
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
}
canvas {
    width: 50vw;
    outline: 1px solid #00ff00;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.160.1/three.min.js"></script>
```

**In the snippet above:**

- the green and red arrows show the acceleration and velocity vectors.
- the function which instantiates `Pendulum` calls the pendulum's `theta` getter (each frame) to rotate it by the angle theta in the three js scene. The theta getter calls all the other getters one by one.

Comment: In your function, through `w.crossVectors(axis, v)`, you set the direction of `w` perpendicular to the z axis, so the `w`'s z component is always zero, therefore `dotProduct` is always zero (which is revealed by debugging) and `isClockwise` always `false`. I suppose you wanted to compute the direction of the **w** vector as that of (**r** x **v**) and not (**k** x **v**) (**k** the z axis versor).